# Calling the button action on a foreign page

Tags: javascript

I am looking for information on triggering a button action on another page.

I wrote something like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="https://example.com/shop/product/x/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <script>
        document.getElementsByName("add-to-cart")[0].click()
    </script>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit form">
</form>

<script>
   function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
   }
</script>
```

Shop's button:

```
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="146335" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>
```

I need a script that, after transferring to the store's website, will add the product to the cart for the customer.
Can someone bring me closer to the solution?